# Pyinstaller packaged app crashes on launch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I know this is a problem that's been asked here a bundle of times before, but I'm seriously at my wits end with this thing. 
I'm learning Python 3 and I decided I'd work on a little text based game. I made some good progress, got most of a tutorial done, title card, half of a save file system written, etc. I decided, hey, I should try and see if I can package this thing before I go any further (because where's the fun in not showing your friends?).

I've used Pyinstaller before on some simple one file apps (dice rollers, etc.) and it worked flawlessly. However, I'm having a hell of a time with my larger game.

When I bundle it with Pyinstaller it throws a *ton* of missing lib errors. I Googled around and those are apparently not a huge issue. Aside from that, everything seems to have run just fine... until I go to launch the program. It's just a simple program that runs in the command line, but when I launch it it crashes immediately.

Now, I thought maybe this had to do with the modules I imported (or the fact that the program relies on calling from multiple .py files). So I made a smaller program that includes all the same imports and calls to an external file, and that one packaged and launched just fine! So at this point, the working hypothesis is that there's something rightly messed with my code, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Here's a link to the program itself: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ouog4ccbibpibgx/AsciiLand.zip?dl=0

Seriously, I've been at this all day and I've made exactly zero progress. Any help would be *greatly* appreciated here guys.

Comment: It might help to view errors associated with the crash. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949336/pyinstaller-exe-does-not-produce-expected-outcome/49949434#49949434 If you cannot address the errors yourself, add them to your question as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I found the problem. While it honestly just raises more problems, I'm gonna accept it for now.

Looks like Pyinstaller has some serious issues with PyFiglet. Everything compiled fine when I removed the PyFiglet output. I have absolutely *zero* idea as to why, but oh well.

For anyone in the future looking for answers to this, here's the command for compiling. You just need to add the Pyfiglet fonts directory to pyinstaller.

pyinstaller --add-data "C:/Python36/Lib/site-packages/pyfiglet";./pyfiglet --onefile myprogram.py